# Function is undefined in a class component react

Tags: reactjs

I transfered the function from render method to be inside the class and I get ('btnClick' is not defined  no-undef) on my function, I don't understand why.

```
class Generator extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
        onView: '0',
        minNum: 0 ,
        maxNum: 100
      } 
    }

    btnClick = () => {
      const { minNum, maxNum } = this.state;
      console.log(minNum);
     };

  render() {

  return (
    <div className="container">
    <Instructions />
    <Range 
      max={this.state.maxNum} 
      min={this.state.minNum} 
      />
    <Generate currentClick={btnClick}/>
    <View show={this.state.onView}/>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Generator;
```

Comment: use this.btnClick

Answer (score 1):

you forgot. the this.

Do this this.btnClick

Answer (score 1):

Inside a React.Component class, you have to use `this` to refers to internal functions (or methods).

In your case, you should do `<Generate currentClick={this.btnClick} />` or `<Generate currentClick={() => this.btnClick()} />`

Comment: Attention : It isn't good pratice for the second method that you writed : {() => this.btnClick()} because it will generate a new reference each new render in component. It isn't good for performance in React.

Answer (score 1):

try `<Generate currentClick={this.btnClick}/>`
mistyped 'this'

Answer (score 0):

You must write

```
 <Generate currentClick={this.btnClick}/>
```

Bonus : For the declaration of functions in class component React, you used the arrow function here, it's good for the shared **context "this"** of class.

```
btnClick = () => {
//...
}
```